# HTML Form submitted to PHP script not working

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a HTML form that posts contact information to a PHP script that mirrors the same page and validates the inputs.
Here is the HTML code on the first page:

```
<p><span class="error">* required field.</span></p>
<form action="http://academic1.bellevue.edu/users/CIS33715/validate.php" method="POST">
Full Name: 
<input type="text" name="name"/>
<span class="error">* </span></br>
Phone #: 
<input type="text" name="phone"/>
<span class="error">* </span></br>
Street Address: 
<input type="text" name="street"/>
<span class="error">* </span></br>
City: 
<input type="text" name="city"/>
<span class="error">* </span></br>
State: 
<input type="text" name="state"/>
<span class="error">* </span></br>
Zip Code: 
<input type="text" name="zip"/>
<span class="error">* </span></br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

The next page is a php script that basically prints the same page in HTML while running the PHP code to validate the form input and display error messages if the input is invalid.

Here is PHP script:

```
<?php
// define variables and set to empty values
$nameErr = $phoneErr = $streetErr = $cityErr = $stateErr = $zipErr = "";
$name = $phone = $street = $city = $state = $zip = "";

// start script if the form is submitted
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
    $nameErr = "Name is required";
}   
else {$name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
    // check if name only contains letters and whitespaces
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
        $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
    }
}

if (empty($_POST["phone"])) {
    $phoneErr = "Phone # is required";
} 
else {$email = test_input($_POST["phone"]);
    // check if phone only contains numbers and dashes in correct format
    if (!preg_match("/^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$/",$phone)) {
        $phoneErr = "Please resubmit Phone # in the following format: 555-    555-5555"; 
    }
}

    if (empty($_POST["street"])) {
    $streetErr = "Address is required";
} 
else {$street = test_input($_POST["street"]);
     // check if address syntax is valid
     if (!preg_match("/^[0-9a-zA-Z. ]+$/",$street)) {
   $streetErr = "Address appears to be invalid.";
     }
   }

        if (empty($_POST["city"])) {
     $cityErr = "City is required";
}
else {$city = test_input($_POST["city"]);
 // check if city syntax is valid
     if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$city)) {
      $cityErr = "City appears to be invalid." ; 
 }
}

    if (empty($_POST["state"])) {
 $stateErr = "State is required";
} 
    else {$state = test_input($_POST["state"]);
 // check if state is valid uppercase abbv. and two letters
     if (!preg_match("/^(A[LKSZRAP]|C[AOT]|D[EC]|F[LM]|G[AU]|HI|I[ADL N]
     |K[SY]|LA|M[ADEHINOPST]|N[CDEHJMVY]|O[HKR]|P[ARW]|RI|S[CD] 
     |T[NX]|UT|V[AIT]|W[AIVY])$/",$state)) {
         $stateErr = "State appears to be invalid. (Hint...Use Upper-case!)" ; 
       }
   }

    if (empty($_POST["zip"])) {
    $zipErr = "Zip Code field is required";
}   
    else {$zip = test_input($_POST["zip"]);
    // check if zip only contains numbers and dashes in correct format
    if (!preg_match("/^[0-9]{5}-[0-9]{4}$/",$phone)) {
        $phoneErr = "Please resubmit Zip Code in the following format: 55555-5555"; 
    }
}

function test_input($data) {
   $data = trim($data);
   $data = stripslashes($data);
   $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
   return $data;
 }
 ?>

<p><span class="error">* required field.</span></p>
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="POST">
Full Name: 
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name;?>"/>
<span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span></br>
Phone #: 
<input type="text" name="phone" value="<?php echo $phone;?>"/>
<span class="error">* <?php echo $phoneErr;?></span></br>
Street Address: 
<input type="text" name="street" value="<?php echo $street;?>"/>
<span class="error">* <?php echo $streetErr;?></span></br>
City: 
<input type="text" name="city" value="<?php echo $city;?>"/>
<span class="error">* <?php echo $cityErr;?></span></br>
State: 
<input type="text" name="state" value="<?php echo $state;?>"/>
<span class="error">* <?php echo $stateErr;?></span></br>
Zip Code: 
<input type="text" name="zip" value="<?php echo $zip;?>"/>
<span class="error">* <?php echo $zipErr;?></span></br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>

<?php
echo "<h2>Your Input:</h2>;"
echo $name;
echo "<br>";
echo $street;
echo "<br>";
echo $city;
echo "<br>";
echo $state;
echo "<br>";
echo $zip;
echo "<br>";
echo $phone;
?>
```

Thanks for any help you can provide. When I submit the form on the first page it brings me to a blank HTML page with no errors or anything.

I have verified that other students PHP pages are working so its nothing wrong with the server.

Comment: Sounds like you need error reporting turned on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a syntax error.

```
echo "<h2>Your Input:</h2>;"
echo $name;
```

which should read

```
echo "<h2>Your Input:</h2>";
echo $name;
```

Turn on error_reporting for development, and maybe use an IDE with error highlighting.

Also, you have a missing brace that should close `if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {` before the function `test_input($data)`

Maybe indent properly too. Discipline prevents headaches.

Comment: its not the only problem.

Comment: Thanks a bunch this fixed it... I didn't think the problem was related to syntax!!!

Comment: Also I am not quite sure how I should be indenting/formatting PHP as I am brand new to this language and also I copy/pasted a lot of code from other files I was creating to find the best way to complete the assignment. Anyway, thank you for your help!

Comment: @Viscocent Could you copy a section that is the worst and show me how it should look so I can change my formatting in the future?

Comment: @midrigs a syntax error will stop code form running. Google "indenting php code" or similar.

Comment: @midrigs post your code here http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ so we can review it there and post a revision code. since i cant post code in this comment section.

Answer (score 0):

There is a missing **}** at line 90 of the second page of code that needs to close the entire **if** statement.  Add it just before the **test_input()** function.  This is additional to the incorrect placement of the semi-colon that Popnoodles mentioned.

Good coding,

c0p

Comment: Hi. An addendum to a previous answer (even though I covered the point you added) should not be posted as an answer. You have enough points to add a comment to an answer.

Comment: That's a glaringly obvious statement but thanks.  I had been working through the issue, submitted an answer, and saw that you had edited your own answer.  See the time stamps?  Take care,

Comment: Ok. The time stamps have this answer as being posted two minutes after my edit. Apparently the statement is not glaringly obvious enough.